# How can I Inform my Project that it is under SCM control?

Tags: xcode, svn, xcode4

I have a problem with XCode 4.0.2 and SVN.

I want to assign a repository to an existing project. [Here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/03/version-control-is-your-friend.html), there is a tutorial about how to do it with Xcode 3. My problem is with section ' Not Quite Done Yet! on previous link

How can I Inform my Project that it is under SCM control?

Answer (score 0):

It should be covered in the [XCode4: Repositories, Snapshots, and Archives](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/SCM/SCM.html)

> In Xcode 4, you configure SCM repositories in the Organizer (Figure 7-2) instead of a preference pane, as is done in Xcode 3.
>   If you check a project or workspace out of Subversion or Git using the command line or another tool, you can add it to your Xcode SCM repository support.
>
> To do so, click the plus sign (`+`) at the bottom of the navigation pane in the repository organizer and choose Add Working Copy.

[image: XCode4 repo config]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that is what I've done. If I right click on any file, and select source control, all suboptions are disabled.

Comment: @VansFannel: so that means you don't have any `.svn` repo in your project right now?

Comment: @VansFannel: then you need to `svn import` your project as described in http://www.interactivewebs.com/blog/index.php/iphone/xcode-4-with-subversion-svn-servertips/

Comment: I've follow your previous instructions, and try to add a working copy, and I get: The working copy could not be added because its repository could not be located. So, I've deleted my project from SVN, and tried to import it again with the same result.

Comment: Ok. Now, I have .svn folder but I can't do a commit, or update. All suboptions are disabled.

Comment: @VansFannel: did you try to close and open XCode4 again?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't work. I have a folder with Xcode project file, and a subfolder with classes and the .svn folder.

Comment: @VansFannel would it be possible to re-import the project, in order to get the XCode4 project file generated right along the classes and `.svn` elements ("right along" = "in the same parent directory than")?

Comment: @VansFannel and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618686/how-to-add-a-new-project-to-source-control-in-xcode-4/5618836 might also help