# Upload a Xcode project to remote svn repository

Tags: xcode, svn, xcode4, objective-c++

I have an Xcode project. It is not connected to a repository. I need to upload it to SVN. How can it be done?

I'm using Xcode 4.0.

Comment: Do you have a svn repository set up?

Comment: I connected to a remote svn repository where I have upload my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built in support for SVN in Xcode 4.  A tip on how to do it is located here :
[How to add a new project to source control in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618686/how-to-add-a-new-project-to-source-control-in-xcode-4)

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly XCode 4.0 had quite some flaws regarding the SVN implementation. One of the major problems was, that you might have to [enter your credentials](http://osdir.com/ml/xcode-users/2011-04/msg00490.html)  in the Terminal before Xcode works with SVN.

However, I would recommend to try the software [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/). It is easy to use, reliable and has a nice GUI.