# Unable to open an ra_local session to URL?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I have a project. I want some form of source control for that project.

I used the answer in [How to add a new project to source control in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618686/how-to-add-a-new-project-to-source-control-in-xcode-4)

So I click organizer, repositories and add a new repositories. Then I want to import my current project. So I click import on the bottom right and point to the directory of my project. I got.

I got this error:

```
svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: Unable to open repository 'file://localhost/business/Dropbox/badgers/BadgerNewFacebook/BadgerNew'
```

What should I do?