# Import a project in SVN from Xcode 5

Tags: ios, svn, xcode5, visualsvn-server

In xcode 4 organizer there was a button "import", in xcode5 how do I import a project in my svn repository?

thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The question is a bit confusing so please advise if it's not exactly what you need (otherwise, feel free to accept the answer). The confusion is that the Xcode 4 workflow you describe is used to allow    developers to manage repositories (svn or git). If you want to take an Xcode project and add it to an existing svn repository I am attaching links to answers for that question.

**Adding Xcode Projects to SVN**:

- [Stack overflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618686/how-to-add-a-new-project-to-source-control-in-xcode-4)
- [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.tour.importing.html)

**High-level Concepts (Xcode 4 Workflow in Xcode 5)**:

- Tell Xcode 5 about a repository (it will auto detect the type of svn
  or git)
- Check-out the repository for insertion into a different project

**Background**:

In Xcode 4.6.3 there was a repository area of the organizer. This is where subversion and git projects were managed.

[image: Xcode 4.6.3 Repositories]

**New Workflow**:

The new location for this information in Xcode 5 is in Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > Repositories (menu on the left) > (+) Add Repository... (on the lower left)

Once selected one may enter a repository address (local or external):
[image: Enter a repo address]

And give the repository a directory name (credentials for many public read only repos are optional):
[image: Repo description]

With Xcode 5, one can then download the repository to a target folder by going to menu Source Control > Check Out...
[image: Repo Checkout]

As part of the checkout wizard one will be authenticated to the repository:
[image: Server Authorization]

Select a target folder to store the local repo:

[image: Select a target folder]

Edit basic repo properties:

[image: Basic Repo Properties]
**For more information on adding projects to repositories**:

[Xcode 5 Source Control Management Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_control_management/UpgradingtoSubversion1/UpgradingtoSubversion1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013353-CH3-SW1)

Comment: How can i view files on the SVN server using xcode 5 svn client

Comment: @iphonedev23 You will need to open a separate question for viewing files on the SVN Server. Generally, you can view files locally after you checkout a working copy of the svn project. (Source Control > Checkout...).. During the process you will see the various trunk, branches, etcetera that are available on the SVN server.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see, you need to know the exact path to be able to check out a project. This seems like a step backwards.

Comment: If you add an extra / to the end of your repository location, it will show you a window so you can browse through your repository