# Could not setup SVN in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, svn, repository, xcode5

I am not able to setup SVN in Xcode 5.
Iv tried these steps:

1) Goto-Xcode-Preferences-Accounts-Add Repositories (clicking "**+**" sign).

2) Enter the url to common server and click next.

3)Enter the credentials. At this point of time i get this error message

[image]

When i click ok i get this screen

[image]

Where do i go from here. No other Option left.

The source control seems to be like this.

[image]

Comment: What is the issue? You have successfully setup your account. In menu you can see "Source Control", you can access svn from there now.

Comment: In source control i can see only one option Checkout

Comment: when i click it i am navigated to the repository containing android apps off course which my colleague had updated using eclipse

Comment: you have tried to add root repository so that may be a problem. Try with your project url

Comment: Project url ??? Hoe do i proceed ??? PLease elaborate a bit

Comment: Try like this -http://YourRepositoryURL/projectName (ex-http://hostname/scm/svn/trunk/projectname)

Comment: Only the project name or the url to the project ??

Comment: @βḧäṙℊặṿῗ : url of the server followed by url of the project name…right ??

Comment: Nah not working….gives this warning "non-existent in revision 48" , and "svn: E200009: Could not display info for all targets because some targets don't exist"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42173/discussion-between-icodeatapple-and-raj-subbiah)

Comment: @iCodeAtApple Did any of the answers below help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Recommendation**

I've answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180718/import-a-project-in-svn-from-xcode-5/19410994#19410994https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180718/import-a-project-in-svn-from-xcode-5/19410994#19410994) and provided references in my earlier answer. Generally speaking you should have been authenticated to the repository (if password is required) and then presented with a target directory. Please note that I am using Xcode 5.0.2 (5A3005).

You could also try importing a sample svn from an offline resource such as the one referenced in the image below. This would help you with validating that everything is correct on your machine/installation. At that point, I'd recommend extrapolating to see how your specific project might be different.

If all else fails you can go to Terminal and use the SVNBook resource from my other question to manually create a local SVN repository and then simply add that to your project. You could then work on adding a remote repo after you have the basics working.

[image: sample svn repo]

Comment: Please help to resolve this question  http://stackoverflow.com/q/21330843/3065953

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is use SVN via commands you can do this by download command online tools this is more reliable then GUI base tool.

Comment: with XCODE 5 command line tools are already downloaded for me…next steps please

Comment: now you just need to open terminal and try some commands these commands are same like common functions which we already do in GUI SVN Clients like Commit, Checkout ,Add, update.

Comment: Please refer this link here you can find almost all commands of SVN and detail about them. http://wiki.greenstone.org/wiki/index.php/Useful_SVN_Commands

Comment: Faheem Rajput : That was helpful…thnxx il try it

Comment: SVN in Xcode never Work for me fine always i found some issue and then i move for any other tool but in vain all are paid  so finally i find that  way which is more powerful and free of cost  you have full control on repo by using this method